# Alternatives of MD5CryptoServiceProvider in CoreCLR (ASP.NET 5 Core)

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core

I am using the new version of ASP.NET MVC 6 (ASP.NET 5). If I target .NET CoreCLR framework (ASP.NET Core) the code doesn't compile because I am using `MD5CryptoServiceProvider` from `System.Security.Cryptography`. Can you suggest any alternatives that compile with the CoreCLR framework?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use [`MD5.Create()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x53bfh67(v=vs.110).aspx) from the package <strike>`System.Security.Cryptography.Hashing.Algorithms`</strike>.
`System.Security.Cryptography.Algorithms`.

**Update**
`System.Security.Cryptography.Hashing.Algorithms` is marked obsolete at the moment.

Comment: Hi, is there an implementation of System.Security.Cryptography.ICryptoTransform for MD5 in dotnet core to use with the CryptoStream ? I would like to read one stream, and write to multiple streams, including incrementaly computed hash streams...

Comment: Found it : System.Security.Cryptography.IncrementalHash.Create(HashAlgorithmName.MD5)

Answer (score 6):

Update to [Victor Hurdugaci's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27239102/3982001): use package `System.Security.Cryptography.Algorithms`.

`System.Security.Cryptography.Hashing.Algorithms` is marked obsolete at the moment.

[image: hint]

Answer (score 5):

For incremental hash, in `System.Security.Cryptography` :

```cs
using (IncrementalHash hasher = IncrementalHash.CreateHash(HashAlgorithmName.MD5))
{
    //hash loop
    hasher.AppendData(data);
    hasher.AppendData(data);
    hasher.AppendData(data);


    byte[] hash = hasher.GetHashAndReset();
}
```